# Is displacement vector fundamental or derived quantity?

Tags: terminology, dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology, displacement

We know that we have 7 fundamental quantities (all scalars) and length is one of them. I classify *velocity* as a derived quantity. What about a position displacement vector? How do I classify *displacement vector*. Is it fundamental or derived quantity?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the convention what to use as a fundamental quantity, but if you refer to [SI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) it is:

- a derived quantity, if you refer to the [electric displacement field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field),

$$ [D] = [\epsilon_0]\cdot [E] = [\epsilon_0]\cdot [F]/[Q] = \mathrm{\frac{A^2\, s^4}{kg\, m^3}\cdot \frac{kg\, m}{s^2}\cdot \left(A\, s\right)^{-1} = \frac{A\, s}{m^2}}. $$

- a fundamental quantity if you refer to a position displacement, because it is a length,

$$ [r] = \mathrm m. $$

Comment: I am referring to a position displacement. Because I asked a question because I saw a question asking 7 fundamental quantities are scalars or vectors. The answer was scalar. So I was a little bit confused that position displacement is a vector not scalar.

Comment: Could you link the question you have just cited? @ofenerci

Comment: Length is a scalar coming from this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67375/is-length-distance-a-vector